# permision denied on port 3000 on nodejs

Tags: node.js, cmd, port, permission-denied, access-denied

when i run my nodejs project on port 3000, get following error:

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
    at Function.listen (F:\Projects\NodeJS\Nodejs start\Nodejs start\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)  
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\NodeJS\Nodejs start\Nodejs start\app.js:34:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
```

Not only on port 3000, but also on any port, the program does not run, and the mentioned error occur.
for solving this problem, i run net stop winnat on CMD, i get:

> The Windows NAT Driver service is not started.

for start the winnat, i run net start winnat , i get

> The Windows NAT Driver service was start successfully.

But the problem was not solved.Is there any other way but to restart the system?

Comment: Antivirus software that is preventing your app from opening up a port?

Answer (score 1):

When reading an environment variable, you should convert it to a number.
Try adding `parseInt()` to the variable:

```
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 3000;
```

Comment: Reading the port number isn't the problem, listening on it is.

Comment: Is something you add when reading the variable, but will impact for sure on the listener. I had the same problem and looked up it on the internet, but nothing fixed it. Until I tried this conversion and then I could listen without a problem. Did you try it?

Comment: You can see from the error message that not interpreting the port number correctly isn't the issue.

Comment: @robertklpe I know the error says 'permission denied' but as I've already said, I had this same issue, apply all these (https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1668) fixes but didn't work. Then I found this solution (do not remember the link) and it works! Lucky me that I could fix this same issue with this line then. I'm trying to leave this comment so could help someone else. In my environment, worked just fine, and now, node is running. Sometimes what works for some people, just doesn't for others. In my case, this was the solution. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

- You can try On Windows systems, restarting the service "Host Network
  Service" may resolve the issue.
- or try to restart your computer more than one time
- or try [open CMD](https://medium.com/@Bartleby/ports-are-not-available-listen-tcp-0-0-0-0-3000-165892441b9d) under admin rights and run :

  net stop winnat

  net start winnat